# Can't stop Android from re-connecting after BluetoothGatt.close()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

This seems like a strange question since most complaints I see are the reverse; one can't get the Android to auto-reconnect to a BTLE device without user intervention.

**Normal behavior**

In this case I connect to a BTLE device and on disconnect, I invoke BluetoothGatt.connect() and do not call BluetootGatt.close(). Now under normal conditions this will result in what I want. When the device re-advertises some time later, the Android will reconnect to it without user intervention.

**Shutdown of the App**

Now I want to shut down my app. So what I do is systematically remove all my BluetoothGattCallback objects. Each of these objects represent an ongoing or pending BTLE connection. The removal involves sending disconnects and finally calling BluetoothGatt.close() on each of these objects.

**The problem**

However, when the device starts advertising again, it gets a connection event from the Android. But there is no application left to handle it. The device remains in that state but makes no progress as the BTLE heart beat packets are continuously exchanged. Of course, the device could time out and disconnect but I see the problem as being on the Android. I can't shut it up!

**One Lousy solution**

What I can do is to turn off Bluetooth on the Android. That releases the connection and the device disconnects. I do not see that as a valid solution.

**Happens on all Androids I have tried**

This behavior is observed on all Android devices I have tried, so there must be something I am doing wrong in the shutdown of the BluetoothCallback objects. *Is this 'keep alive' a consequence of the pending connect()?*

Answer (score 0):

No as long as you close, Android will remove the pending connection (unless there are other BluetoothGatt objects that refers to the same device in some other app). Do you have any other running BLE apps on the phone?

You could also call disconnect() followed by close() which should do the same thing but might sometimes work better if the Android device has a buggy BLE stack. Which devices have you tested on?

Comment: I do call disconnect and Gatt.close() when I shut down the app. However, I might be up against the Android ambiguity that even though I shut down the app, Android may choose to keep it in the background. And you are right to the extent that different platforms appear to respond differently. I noted this problem primarily on the Moto E4 and some other platforms. But the Galaxy Nexus 5 does not seem to behave in the same manner. The same code is running on all ...

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I will give another answer that I discovered while setting up my Android app. It seems that a connection process is only terminated when the BluetoothGatt instance is ready to be garbage collected (all references to the instance have been deleted). I'm not entirely sure this is the case but it definitely fixed my problem by being very selective where I grab the reference and where I set my local variable to null.